# A way to have my BroadcastReceiver block broadcast from system?

Tags: java, android, camera, broadcastreceiver

I am writing an Android app where the user can take pictures and I am using my own camera functionality instead of Androids built in camera software.  It all works fine except I want to be able to take a picture when the user presses the hard camera button.  I registered a Broadcast receiver, and it works but Android still opens its camera program over my app.  Is there a way to block the built in app from receiving the broadcast?

I am posting my code below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

```
  //Listen for camera button to be pressed
    cameraButtonListener = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera Button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
    //register broadcast receiver to listen for camera button
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(cameraButtonListener,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [abortBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29) in conjunction with [android:priority](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestIntentFilter_priority) set to high to "consume" the broadcast. However, this works only if the broadcast is an Ordered broadcast, and I don't know what type is ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
if("android.intent.action.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON".equals(intent.getAction()))
```

in register

```
 getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(cameraButtonListener,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON) );
```